# How to set initial value for primary key in migration?

Tags: yii2

I'm creating migration in Yii2, and would like to set initial value for primary key column (for example id = 100) for only one table, but by default it set to 1. Is it possible to change initial value of primary key?

Thanks in advance.

```
class m190723_083518_create_all_tables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $this->createTable('table', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            ....
        ]);
    }
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `$options` argument in [`createTable()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-migration#createTable()-detail) method:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $this->createTable('table', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        // ...
    ], 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=100');
}
```